# How to change properties of express function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, types

In the express `Request.send` function, the basic input types accepted into the `send` function is stated as `(property) Response<any>.send: (body?: any) => Response<any>` in VS Code. Can I change this function from `any` to another type? I want to do this so I can force myself to only send a specific JSON object to the front end on every end point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the original `res` param to create the one you need:

```js
type ArgumentsType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (
  ...args: infer A
) => any
  ? A
  : never;

type Args = ArgumentsType<typeof app.get>; // get the arguments of app.get
type subApplication = Args[1]; // select the second param, the function
type application = ArgumentsType<subApplication>; // get the argument of the funcion
type res = application[1]; // select the second param: res

// Extend res and overwrite the original send method
interface myCustomRes extends res {
  send: (arg: object) => any; // force send to only admit object
}

app.get("/", function (req, res: myCustomRes) {
  res.send("Hello World!"); // Error because we are using string
  res.send({ message: "Hello World!" }); // Ok because we are using object!
});
```

[Check the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/express-typescript-forked-yghbw?file=/src/index.ts:218-780)